# Trim() and Replace(" ", "") not removing white space in C#

Tags: c#, string, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace

I am trying to write "text" into a file with

```
private void WriteToLogs(string text)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(todayMessageLog, $"({DateTime.Now}) Server Page: \"{text.Trim()}\"\n");
    }
```

The text comes out as this:
"text (a bunch of white space)"

The text string is made up of these:

```
string username = e.NewClientUsername.Trim().Replace(" ", "");
string ip = e.NewClientIP.Trim().Replace(" ", "");

WriteToLogs($"{username.Trim().Replace(" ", "")} ({ip.Trim().Replace(" ", "")}) connected"); // NONE OF THESE WORKED FOR REMOVING THE WHITE SPACE
```

The "e" parameter comes from a custom EventArgs class in another namespace and NewClientIP and NewClientUsername are properties inside the class

As you can see, I tried with both Trim and Replace on both the strings themselves and the method but nothing removes the white space.

Comment: _The text comes out as this: "text (a bunch of white space)"_ - can you provide an axact representation of the white space? Not how it’s printed, but exactly what characters it’s composed of.

Comment: I couldnt provide it in my post because stackoverflow trims the text but i can explain it i guess, it comes out as: (7/31/2021 1:15:16 AM) Server Page: "soxketsUser: sfa                                                " (if you cant see the white space, there is 48 spaces after "sfa")

Comment: I ask because you say your code to replace spaces ‘doesn’t work’. There are two possibilities as I see it - the code isn’t actually being called (which seems unlike.y from your question code) or the white space isn’t actually ‘spaces’. Can you create a minimal code example to reproduce the problem? If the code formatting on SO won’t allow this, you can link to an external code site like https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @stuartd ive kind of explained it badly because what im doing is writing to a log file and ive given you an example of the same problem im having but with another output.. here is the real example: I couldnt provide it in my post because stackoverflow trims the text but i can explain it i guess, it comes out as: (7/31/2021 1:54:36 AM) Server Page: "soxketsUser                                                      (127.0.0.1:50331) connected" (there is 54 spaces after "soxketsUser")

Comment: Try printing the result with something like `BitConverter.ToString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text))` instead. It is likely that the empty characters are not SPACES (would show as 20-20-20-...) but something else.

Comment: @Yirkha the white space shows up as 00, not 20, how can i remove it?

Comment: @demented Just Trim()/Replace() with '\0',  '\x00', "\0" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Trim()` and `Replace()` methods do not work, the string is likely not padded with the usual white-space characters like SPACE or TAB, but something else. There are many other characters which can show up blank.

Try printing the result with something like `BitConverter.ToString(Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text))`. Spaces would show up as 20-20-20-..., but you will probably get something else.

---

> The white space shows up as 00, not 20, how can I remove it?

Good. Use the argument to the [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-5.0#System_String_Trim_System_Char___) method, like so:

```cs
var text = "Blah\0\0\0\0";
text.Length            → 8
text.Trim('\0').Length → 4
```

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH ILY

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this working for you

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    //This is your text 
    string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   "+
        "This is   text with   far  too   much   "+
        "This is   text with   far  too   much   ";
        
      //This is the Regex
      string pattern = "\\s";
        
      //Value with the replace
      string replacement = "";
        
      //Replace 
      string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
      
      //Result
      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim *white spaces* (not only `' '`, but `\t`, `\U00A0` etc.) as well as `\0` (which is *not* white space), you can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

// Trim whitespaces and \0
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(^[\s\0]+)|([\s\0]+$)", "");
```

For reference

```
// Trim start whitespaces and \0
string resultStart = Regex.Replace(input, @"^[\s\0]+", "");

// Trim end whitespaces and \0
string resultEnd = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\s\0]+$", "");
```

Same idea (regular expressions), but different pattern if you want not to *trim* but *remove* white spaces and `\0`:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\s\0]+", "");
```